# Format CSS rules to be on a single line

Tags: css

so im having this issue with my CSS, im trying to write my CSS code the normal way like this, but i want it vertical

```
.topic_row {
height:60px;
}table
.reputation {
right:0px;
position:absolute;

.topic_row {
height:60px;
}table
.reputation {
right:0px;
position:absolute;

.rep_bar {
background:#FFF;
font-size:1.1em !important;
-moz-border-radius-topleft:5px;border-radius-topleft:5px;
-webkit-border-top-left-radius:5px;
padding:0px;
right:10px;
bottom:45px;
position:absolute;
width:150px

.rep_bar
ul {
margin-top:8px;
float:left

.rep_bar ul
li {
float:left;
margin:0
2px

p.rep_highlight {
float:left;
display:inline-block;
margin:5px
10px 10px 10px;
background:#D5DEE5;
color:#1d3652;
padding:5px;
-moz-border-radius:5px;
border-radius:5px;
-webkit-border-radius:5px;
font-size:0.8em;
font-weight:bold;
text-align:center

p.rep_highlight
img{
margin-bottom:4px

.reputation{
float:none;
text-align:center;
/*margin-left:10px;*/
margin-right:10px

.reputation.negative, .members
li.negative{
background:#b82929;
color:#fff

.reputation.zero{
background:#CCC;
color:#6e6e6e
```

But i want it vertical since my style for the forums only accepts vertical for some reason, so i need it all the code formated in a straight line like this:

```
.pun .fakeform{PADDING:20px 20px 15px 20px}
```

And i do not know how to format it like this, so if someone has the time, and effort to format all of the code above to a straight vertical line i'd appriciate it!

Thank you.

Comment: What you mean with vertical CSS? If you just want some sort of formatting you can use any decent IDE to format your code to your liking's.

Comment: "_i do not know how to format it like this_" Maybe I am missing something but can't you just use backspace to remove all the line breaks? What is the difficulty? Also, I think you have vertical and horizontal mixed up - vertical means up and down.

Answer (score 0):

Something like [stylelint](https://stylelint.io) with the `--fix` option should solve your issue. See https://stylelint.io/user-guide/rules for documentation on all stylelint rules.

Here, the following stylelint rules would be most relevant:

- [`block-opening-brace-newline-before: never-multi-line`](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/rules/block-opening-brace-newline-before/#never-multi-line)
- [`block-opening-brace-newline-after: never-multi-line`](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/rules/block-opening-brace-newline-after/#never-multi-line)
- [`block-closing-brace-newline-before: never-multi-line`](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/rules/block-closing-brace-newline-before/#never-multi-line)
- [`block-closing-brace-newline-after: never-multi-line`](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/rules/block-closing-brace-newline-after/#never-multi-line)

Relevant stylelint documentation pages:

- [Stylelint configuration guide](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/configuration)
- [Stylelint CLI](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/cli) / [Stylelint editor plugins](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/complementary-tools/#editor-plugins)
- [Stylelint CLI's autofix switch (`--fix`)](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/complementary-tools/#editor-plugins)